# How to get HTML <textarea> value using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, get, textarea

How can I get the value of a textarea  using c# ?

my issue is when I using MultiLine TextBox I can't get the full value !! I mean what I wrote including the 
 breake lines.
ex:

1. Google
2. Micrisoft
3. Yahoo

after saving above data it come's in one line
1.Google 2.Microsoft 3.Yahoo

Comment: Can you give us a little more context to understand exactly what you're tying to do?

Comment: He's trying to get the value, i.e. text of a textarea - lots of people who don't know what a textarea is, and yet still comment/answer/vote to close .. weird!

Comment: Edited by Kieren Johnstone: I tidied up your grammar, guessed you were using ASP.NET and re-tagged this question.

Answer (score 1):

the very first result on Google showed me this:

> http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread26856.html

1- *I right clicked the TEXTAREA and made it RUN as a Server Control....Its working fine..*

2- *You can also set the "multiline" property of the standard TextBox control. That control will either render an  element or a  element, depending on the properties you set.* // *TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine*

Simply create a `TextBox`, set `TextMode` to `MultiLine`, then you can get the text using the `.Text` property on your `TextBox` object.

It's always worth trying to find the solution for yourself first, then try it out, make mistakes and ask questions.  It's the best way to learn.

Comment: my issue is when I using MultiLine TextBox I can't get the full value !! I mean what I wrote including the <BR> breake lines.

ex:

Google

Microsoft


Yahoo


- after saving above data it come's in one line


Google microsoft yahoo

Comment: Please confirm 100% that the value coming back from the textbox has no line breaks in it.  You say 'after saving' - do you mean to a database?  How are you checking that there are no newlines or line breaks.  They will not be <BR>, they will be newlines (\n).

Comment: 1- Yes " in database ". 2- Iam checking that by checking the column value in my database. 3- also there is no (\n)

Comment: Which database?  How are you checking?  Some DB management tools will show all lines one after the other.

Comment: SQL2005 - just see what saved. should be like: "1-Google<br/>2-Yahoo"

Comment: http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/chrismay/entry/how_are_newlines/ they are stored as newlines (CRLF, 0x0D,0x0A, \r\n) not <BR/>

Comment: You should learn to be more specific when asking for help, for example 'just see what saved' still doesn't say whether you are running a query, using Enterprise Manager, browsing the tables, whether you're just reading the value of a cell or printing it out in a stored proc, copy-and-pasting somewhere, doing an actual programmatic search for a newline character, and so on.  I'm going on about this because its more likely that you're not looking for the newline in the right way.  Even after saying it before, you're still looking for <BR> :)

Comment: I think it is hard on you to understand the question. every things clear. you are asking about something not related to the question.

Comment: I understand the question perfectly.  It is a very simple question.  If you are looking for <BR>s in the Text value, you will not find them.  You should be looking for the ASCII characters \r\n or their escaped counterparts, %0D%0A.

Comment: Well - did you find any newlines?  How were you looking in the end?  (Table browser in Management Studio? Stored proc? Client code? Reading from the DB and displaying in HTML?)

Answer (score 1):

I made this in Visual Basic (easy translation to C#):

```
Dim convertedtext As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
```

and then, I saved convertedtext to the database. TextBox1 is the multiline textbox.

If you enconde the data to show it again (in a literal or similar) do the following:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(convertedtext).Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<br />"), "<br />")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand the question - but maybe you want to look at the [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) method of the graphics class.